# How to insert path with variable in it?

Tags: php, mysql, path

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

for($i=7;$i<=150;$i++)
{
$res= mysql_query("INSERT INTO pokemons (pk_name, pk_type, path) VALUES ('nm', 'typ', '<img src=/images/'".$i."'.png>')");  
echo $res;

}
```

I tried a simple insert php code which would insert image path. 
Its not showing any error..and technically its correct! Then too rows are not added?

Comment: was it printing anything ?

Comment: then it is not going inside `if{}`. check whether really `submit` was posted

Comment: well, now i runned it..I am getting the sql statements 151! as i used echo...! but still data entry is not done!

Comment: check query has executed successfully or not by using `or die(mysql_error())` with `mysql_query()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    for($i=7;$i<=150;$i++)
    {
        $res= mysql_query("INSERT INTO pokemons (pk_name, pk_type, path) VALUES ('nm', 'typ', '<img src=/images/".$i.".png>')");            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you  missed one curly bracket to close if condition

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    for($i=7;$i<=150;$i++)
    {
       $res= mysql_query("INSERT INTO pokemons (pk_name, pk_type, path) VALUES ('nm', 'typ', '<img src=/images/'".$i."'.png>')");  
       var_dump($res);

    }
}
?>
```

**note : $res is resource , you can print it .. try `var_dump($res)` instead**

try to write indented code, it will help you to trace brackets easily

Also check if mysql connection is successful or not

you can append **die()** on **mysql_query()** like below

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO pokemons (pk_name, pk_type, path) VALUES ('nm', 'typ', '<img src=/images/'".$i."'.png>')") or die(mysql_error())
```

Comment: } was present.. i just missed it while copying.. there are not errors! the code is running but data entry is not done??

Answer (score -1):

php variable $i shoudn't be in ""

```
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    for($i=7;$i<=150;$i++)
    {
       $res= mysql_query("INSERT INTO pokemons (pk_name, pk_type, path) VALUES ('nm', 'typ', '<img src=/images/'.$i.'.png>')");  
       var_dump($res);

    }
}
?>
```